# Display DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, enums

I am trying to build a drop down list using `enum`.
I tried the following, but do not know how to display it in view. I am using `MVC framework`

```
 public enum Condition
        {
            And,
            Or,
            Not,
        }

 private List<Condition> userTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Condition)).Cast<Condition>().ToList();

       public List<Condition> UserType
       {
           get
           {
               return userTypes;
           }
           set
           {
               userTypes = value;
           }
       }
```

Is the above code right to display a simple drop down list?
And how do I pass in it view to display drop down list.
Thanks

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1787493.aspx?enum+to+drop+down+list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `Action` :

```
ViewData["ddl"] = userTypes.Select(t => new SelectListItem { Text = t.ToString(), Value = ((int)t).ToString() });
```

in your `aspx` :

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("ddl", ViewData["ddl"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
```

> Rest of this is alright.

Answer (score 1):

You suppose to return `string` list from property `UserType` not `Condition` type. Secondly property must is of `readonly` since enum is constant and user won`t going to change it. Lastly don't use variable, property itself handle this.

```
public List<string> UserType
{
   get
   {
      return Enum.GetNames(typeof(Condition)).ToList();
   }
}
```

Comment: @RS26 Don't know much about mvc but I think Ashok's answer will help you to pass property to your .aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your model add a List like:

   ```
    private List conditionList= Enum.GetValues(typeof(Condition))
                       .Cast()
                       .Select(e => new SelectListItem { Value = ((int)e).ToString(), Text      = e.ToString() });
   ```
2. And Then just add this on your view

   ```
   @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Condition,Model.conditionList)
   ```

I believe that will make things more easier.